Solution formula in an explicit equation over $\mathbb{F}_p^3$
I'm looking into a formula involving prime numbers $p \geq 7$ and an equation's solutions. The equation in question is:
$$z^2 = (x^2 - 4x)(y^2 - 4y)((x + 1 - y)^2 - 4x),$$
where $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{F}_p^3$.
Through some computer calculations for primes up to 2741, I've noticed something interesting when the Jacobi symbol $\left(\frac{p}{15}\right)$ equals -1. Depending on the congruence condition of $p$  modulo $15$, $N_p$, the number of solutions, seems to follow one of two patterns:

If $p\equiv 7,13 (\bmod{15} )$, then $N_p = p^2 + 2p + 2$.
If $p\equiv 11,14 (\bmod{15} )$, then $N_p = p^2 - 2p + 2$.

I'm trying to figure out why this happens and if this formula remains true for all primes where $\left(\frac{p}{15}\right) = -1$. Any thoughts or guidance on this would be helpful!

Some quick thoughts (1) An equation of the form $z^2=f(x,y)$ with $f$ of degree $6$ defines, if the singularities of $f$ are not too bad, a singular surface birational to a K3 surface. (2) A formula of the kind you write down is exactly what you get for a K3 surface with CM by the field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-15})$. So I suspect that your surface is indeed a K3 surface with CM by that field. (3) For such a surface, there is even a formula for $\left(\frac{p}{15}\right)=1$, now expressed in terms of a prime of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-15})$ lying over $p$.
